# Bug? Indented code block not interpreted after list

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

See here:

---

- Item one
- Item Two

  ## this is supposed to be a code comment

  import bpy
  print(bpy.context.scene.name)

  1. this should not be indented I guess

---

1. Item one
2. Item Two

(add something here to fix code block interpretation)

```
import bpy
print(bpy.context.scene.name)
```

---

Am I overlooking something obvious in post formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ambiguity in the [Markdown specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). See [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327/226253).

A quick and simple fix is to do as you've done and put a string of text there. A comment `<!-- -->` should do the job if you need to keep the post clean.

- Item one
- Item Two

```
# this is supposed to be a code comment
import bpy
print(bpy.context.scene.name)
```

1. this should not be indented I guess

Comment: Thanks for clarification! It's not allowed to edit non-wiki posts on meta sites, so can't check the markdown of your post, but not really needed. Will use a comment if needed!